# Untar multiple files in a directory

Tags: command-line, tar

There are multiple .tar files in a directory. I am trying to extract them all.

The following command works

```
for a in $(ls -1 *.tar); do tar -xvf $a; done
```

But when I try following command, it prints all the file names but does nothing. It does not extract the .tar files.

```
% tar -xvf *.tar
Solarized-Dark-Cyan-3.0.3.tar
Solarized-Dark-Green-3.0.3.tar
Solarized-Dark-Magenta-3.0.3.tar
Solarized-Dark-Orange-3.0.3.tar
Solarized-Dark-Red-3.0.3.tar
Solarized-Dark-Violet-3.0.3.tar
```

Why is that, given `unzip '*.zip'` works for multiple .zip files.

Comment: What does your "given" have to do with this? Why should `tar` behave like `unzip` - reinventing shell globbing with its own quirks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unzip` handles `'*.zip'`-style arguments, `tar` doesn’t. There might be archive extractors with this feature, with the ability to extract tarballs, but I’m not aware of any.

You should avoid using `ls` for this:

```
for a in *.tar; do tar -xvf "$a"; done
```

`tar -xvf *.tar` tries to extract the second and further tarballs from the first one, which usually won’t do anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted the confirmation that "tar doesn’t". I thought there is some problem in my terminal (as it is heavily customized). What does it mean to  extract the second and further tarballs from the first one.

Comment: the ZIP tools might originate from a different environment than the Unixy environment where it's usually the shell that handles globs so that not every utility has to.

Comment: @Ahmad if you have `bar.tar`, `baz.tar` and `foo.tar`, `tar -xvf *.tar` expands to `tar -xvf bar.tar baz.tar foo.tar`, which asks `tar` to extract `baz.tar` and `foo.tar` from `bar.tar`.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, Info-ZIP `unzip` was first written for MS-DOS, so it had to do its own glob handling.